# Beamer: Moving text to the bottom of the page

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I am trying to move some text to the bottom of a beamer slide. Why do `\vspace*{\fill}` and `vfill` not work? Luckily `\begin{frame}[b]{Title}` does the job for me (at least for most slides), but I would like to understand why the previously mentioned commands fail to do the job.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[b]{Title}
    This text is correctly bottom aligned.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
    Text\\
    \vspace*{\fill}
    This text is not correctly bottom aligned.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
    Text
    \vfill
    This does not work either.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]{Title}
    Now I am not able to vertically center this text anymore.\\
    \vskip0pt plus 1filll
    This text is now bottom aligned.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like adding `\vskip0pt plus 1filll` before and after the text forces it to be aligned vertically. None of the other `\vspace*{\fill}` and `\vfill` appear to work in the same manner, though.

```
\begin{frame}[c]{Title}
    \vskip0pt plus 1filll
    This text is vertically aligned.\\
    \vskip0pt plus 1filll
    This text is bottom aligned.
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

The motivation behind this difficulty is because [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) puts in considerable effort to manage the content on frames, with the possibility of automatically breaking them into different slides based on `\pause`s and/or overlay specification. Specifically, it inserts skips at the top and bottom of the `frame`, and these interfere with your skips.

If you want content spread across the `frame` it's best to set it inside a `minipage` of appropriate height (guessed based on whether it fits or is overfull):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[b]{Title}
  This text is correctly bottom aligned.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.8715\textheight]{\textwidth}
  Text
  
  \vspace{\fill}% or \vfill

  This text is correctly bottom aligned.
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```